# How to use SSL Web Services in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wsdl, soap4r, wsdl2ruby

I having a hard time to consume this webservice https://www.arello.com/webservice/verify.cfc?wsdl in my rails application.
I successfully generated the ruby files with the wsdl2ruby.rb but when un run the generated script I get the following error:

```
at depth 0 - 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I also tried to connect via this script but same issue

```
require 'http-access2'
client = HTTPAccess2::Client.new()
client.ssl_config.set_trust_ca('/arello.cert')
puts client.get('https://www.arello.com/webservice/verify.cfc?wsdl').content
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to get around this is to just turn off SSL Cert verification.  You can do this with the ssl_config options.  Example from your second script:

```
require 'http-access2'
client = HTTPAccess2::Client.new()
client.ssl_config.verify_mode=OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
puts client.get('https://www.arello.com/webservice/verify.cfc?wsdl').content
```